# Zoom background image with background size cover

Tags: css, background-image

I'm using this code to make a wordpress header picture slowly zoom in and out. It works in Chrome and Firefox, but in Safari it seems like the `background-size: cover` that is set for the picture overrides the zoom. Is there a way to zoom from cover to "150% cover"? Basically tell it to start as cover and then go 150% from there? This code wont even zoom at all in Safari, and `background-size: 100%` doesn't make the picture tall enough on mobile so I'd need a different solution.

Thank you!

```
   @-webkit-keyframes animatedBackground {
      from {
        background-size: 100%;}
     
        50% {
        background-size: 150%; }
    
      to {
        background-size: 100%; }
        
    }
    
    .home .header-media .wrapper:before {
      -webkit-animation: animatedBackground 90s linear infinite;
      -moz-animation: animatedBackground 90s linear infinite;
      animation: animatedBackground 90s linear infinite;
        background-position: center;
        background-size: cover;
    }
```

Comment: Check [this](https://css-tricks.com/zooming-background-images/) out.

Comment: @AsafS. Great! `transform: scale(1.5)` did it in combo with `overflow: hidden` on the container. Thanks!

Comment: Your welcome! I've added an answer, maybe would be useful to others too :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is working snippet, `transition` and `background-size` do the trick.

```css
.parent {
  width: 400px; 
  height: 300px;
}

.child {
  transition: all .5s;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black; /* fallback color */
  background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b4/The_Sun_by_the_Atmospheric_Imaging_Assembly_of_NASA%27s_Solar_Dynamics_Observatory_-_20100819.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100%;
}

.parent:hover .child,
.parent:focus .child {
  background-size: 150%;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Will that work with `background-size: cover` though? Scale() is what did it for me.